# How to use touch start event in Oracle MAF?

Tags: javascript, jdeveloper, gestures, oracle-maf

I have some buttons in my application developed in Oracle MAF - jdeveloper. I am trying to fire the action on every action with finger. For example you ONLY go through Two buttons with your finger without pressing it and the action Is going to start in both of them. Oracle MAF contains only swipe, tap, taphold actions. Is there any way to do the example action?
Maybe some javascript to the existing amx buttons.?

Thank you for every reply.